# Counting Instances For Each Combination of Another Field

Tags: sql, t-sql

I have a table with the following fields:

1. OfficeID
2. PropertyState
3. PropertyAddress
4. PropertyCity

I want to find all of the properties where more than 1 OfficeID opened a file for a specific address (St, City, Addr being equal) and how many files with the same address were opened for each office combination.

For example given the data set below:

```
OfficeID      PropertySt       PropertyCity       PropertyAddr
   1             NC               Raleigh            123 Main St
   1             NC               Raleigh            456 Acorn Ave
   1             NC               Raleigh            789 Blue Rd
   2             NC               Raleigh            123 Main St
   2             NC               Raleigh            321 South St
   3             NC               Raleigh            456 Acorn Ave
   3             NC               Raleigh            789 Blue Rd
   3             NC               Raleigh            987 West St
   4             NC               Raleigh            123 Main St
   4             NC               Raleigh            987 West St
```

I would expect

```
   OfficeCombo   Count
      1/2           1
      1/3           2
      1/4           1
      2/3           0 (this row would not NEED to be returned but is ok to return with a 0)
      2/4           1
      3/4           1
```

Comment: What if there a 3 occurences ? Would the OfficCOmbo look like `1/2/3` ?

Comment: @phadaphunk I think he just copy-pasted the addresses.

Comment: Ideally, there would be multiple lines: 1/2, 1/3, & 2/3 - I am most interested in the combination of 2s

Comment: @McVey you ruined the formatting.. why?

Comment: Fixed the formatting - was having issues.  Thanks for everybody's attention

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick:

```
select
  cast(A.OfficeId as varchar(10)) + '/' +
  cast(B.OfficeId as varchar(10)) as OfficeCombo,
  count(*) as [Count]
from Table1 A join Table1 B
   on A.PropertySt = B.PropertySt
  and A.PropertyCity = B.PropertyCity
  and A.PropertyAddr = B.PropertyAddr
  and B.OfficeId > A.OfficeId
group by A.OfficeId, B.OfficeId
```

The idea is to count how many addresses each pair of offices has in common.

[Here's](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/ce6c0/16) a SQL Fiddle for testing purposes.